# Creating one general page for different users

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Hello all of my friends,

I am a front end developer, I am implementing one dashboard.
I have different users with different permissions in this project. Each of them  able to see some parts of the page. So all the pages(used for different users) have some similarities and some small differences for different users.

What do you suggest me, to implement these pages? let me tell you , till now I have done in this way:
I implemented one main page for manager(with most level permission) and then for different users I have copied that code in other .jsp file and then made some modifications.But actually copy some similar code is not logical.**and here is my problem**

I am looking for some way to create one HTML general , in order to avoid repeat it several times, then call some specific parts of that for different goals(users)

I am using HTML,jsp,CSS,jQuery,javascript for this project

Thank in advance

Comment: Are you using a database?

Comment: Depending on how complex the page will be, you can always use [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load in sections of a HTML page into yours. This could cause some issues with scripting not being loaded.

Comment: Ye I am using DAtabase for populating the data which should palced inside dataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know how to do it in jsp but in our html and mvc project we create some layout pages which consists same background, menu etc. You can use layout page, and call it example pages. By using layout you get one template, different content for different users.

Maybe this helps

- [MVC Layout Usage 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts)
- [MVC Layout Usage 2](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp)